# Declaring variables in function (Fortran)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to write a very simple function in Fortran (first-time user):

```
program Main 
  implicit none 
  integer function k(n) 
    integer, intent(in) :: n 
    k=n 
   end function k 
 end program Main
```

I get a bunch of errors:

```
integer function k(n)
                  1
Error: Syntax error in data declaration at (1)

   integer, intent(in) :: n
                          1
Error: Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)

   end function k
     1
Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)

   k=n
   1
Error: Symbol ‘k’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type

   k=n
     1
Error: Symbol ‘n’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using the last version of gfortran.

Comment: Can you provide some details on how you are compiling and exactly what version of compiler you're using (latest can mean lots of different things) etc? I would guess you need to do `gfortran -c file.f90` rather than `gfortran file.f90` or you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am using gfortran file.f90. I also tried now with added -c, didn't work.
My compiler is gfortran 6.1. El Capitan.

Comment: Does your file just contain exactly what you've written in your question or is there more? If there's more can you provide that (or a minimal version of that) as I can compile the above without an issue.

Comment: This is it:

program Main
  implicit none
  integer function k(n)
  integer, intent(in) :: n
  k=n 
  end function k

end program Main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any declared functions and subroutines local to the program block should be put after a `contains` statement, for example

```
program Main 
  implicit none 
 contains
  integer function k(n) 
    integer, intent(in) :: n 
    k=n 
   end function k 
end program Main
```

To give an example of a program using this you could have

```
program Main 
  implicit none 
  integer :: myLocalN
  myLocalN = 2
  print*, "My local N is ", myLocalN
  print*, "The value of this squared is", sq(myLocalN)
 contains
  integer function sq(n) 
    integer, intent(in) :: n 
    sq=n*n 
   end function sq
end program Main
```

Comment: Thanks! Now if I want to print, say, k(3), how do I do it?
I tried to add a print *, k(3) statement after end function k, but I get an error: Unexpected WRITE statement in CONTAINS section at (1)

Comment: @odnerpmocon I've edited my answer to include an example. Essentially your main program statements should come before the `contains` block.